# stringByAppendingPathComponent adds a '/' character to the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have the following code:

```
NSString *message;
if (some_condition) {
    message = @"String 1. ";
} else {
    message = @"String 2. ";

}
message = [message stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bla bla bla."];
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                               message:message
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

The text that I see when the alert pops up has an extra '/' character where the string were appended:

[image: String 2. /Bla bla bla.]

Where did it come from and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong method there.

Instead of :

```
message = [message stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bla bla bla."];
```

Use:

```
message = [message stringByAppendingString:@"Bla bla bla."];
```

When you use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` it will return a new string made by appending the provided string to the receiver, preceded if necessary by a path separator.

Reference : [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1417069-stringbyappendingpathcomponent?language=objc)